# where is NSLog defined, ie. what is the header for NSLog?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am the newbie for Mac OS programming. I am wondering where is the NSLog get defined?

Comment: 1) you probably mean `NSLog`, which you do not need to include anything for.  2) Is your question in regards to Mac OS programming, or ios programming?

Answer (score 6):

In the **NSObjCRuntime.h** file:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of "teaching a man to fish", you can find the definition of any symbol by putting the cursor in it in the code editor, then either looking at the quick help on the right, or right-clicking and selecting "jump to definition".

Answer (score 2):

It's in the `Foundation` framework, in `NSObjCRuntime.h`. Here's the def:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

You can see where methods are defined at the end of [the documentation for the method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog):

> **Declared In**
>   NSObjCRuntime.h

Comment: That link is dead.